# Mule Flow Processing Strategy

Tags: asynchronous, mule

I created an Asynchronous Processing Block to send to a message to JMS when some value processed on the flow is true. However, I have to choose what strategy to apply to this asynchronous block. I'm torn in 2 strategies:

The default one: **queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy** or

The **asynchronous-processing-strategy**. On the documentation they say to choose this last one when "for some reason you do not want your processing to be distributed across nodes". The question is: What are those distributed nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distributed nodes refer to different Mule instances you have run as part of a cluster. If you are using a queued strategy the message can be picked up by any of the nodes. If you are just using `asynchronous-processing-strategy` then it will always run on the same node but just in a different thread.